Make a reverse engineering for dead app
Hi,there is an app (Voip Recorder & Screen Recorder)the developer stopped updating the app from 3 years, and it's the only app in the world could record the screen with internal sound likes Instagram calls and Whatsapp...etc
The app: google play link
Is there any chance to decompile the app and make one like it ?
NOTE: IT'S WORKING WITH ROOT

Have you asked the developer why it is no longer updated? Often the app developer already know what is going wrong and can tell it to you. The more information you get, the easier is it to understand if there is a possibility and how difficult it will get.

@Robert he doesn't reply to anyone at all.
